# Which kinds of congresspeople are richer than others?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate

As far as I'm aware, the public data exists to disclose the net worth of US Senators/House members both as they enter Congress, and as they leave it (or current data if they are active).

Is there any good research on what the relative **average** net worth is for **different political groupings of Congresspeople**, both at their entrance when first elected, and at their retirement (or current networth for those still serving)?

I'm interested in analysis across all sorts of groupings - both the more obvious (party membership, or which house they are in) as well as less obvious, such as radicalism/moderation as defined by for example DW-Nominate; or establishment vs. outsiders; pre-congress careers; geography; length of elected service; decade when they were first elected; etc...  Pretty much any grouping that someone like Nate Silver would find scientific enough to measure things across would be of interest.

**Ideally, a good answer would include some sort of regression analysis to show which of the grouping factors correlate and/or predict net worth best.**

Comment: This might be a source worth digging into. Looks like they've listed the 50 richest congresspeople for the past 30 years: http://www.rollcall.com/50richest/

Comment: @DA. - Fun. 2 top ones are basically gold diggers (one married to Clear Channel communication heiress, one to Heinz).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Congress_by_wealth

Comment: @raxman - (and DA too) - this (1) only lists top ones. I am interested in group averages for all; (2) only lists 2012 current members wealth. I'm interested in pre-Congress wealth as well; (3) Has zero research on groupings, which if you read carefully was the most important thing I was after.

Comment: congress has pretty much always been mostly rich white men regardless of party affiliation. Little is made of it though because neither party really wants to talk about it.

Comment: @Ryathal - example of a rich white man: Dianne Feinstein.

Comment: @DVK its 2013 the feminist movement has succeeded in turning congress from the rich white mens club to the rich white club

Comment: None of the congress critters, not even the richest, can hold a candle to delegates in China's People's Congress like Wang Jianlin ($10.3 billion) or Liang Wengen ($ 7.3 billion). That's BEEL-YON, not million, and DOLLARS, not yuan.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel - Impressive! I suspect Russian officials are also safely out of poverty :)

Comment: [WSJ article](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424127887323723104578187360101389762.html#) (I expect this comment to be deleted as off-topic but hopefully not before DVK has a chance to read it; apologies to Mods for creating extra work.)

Comment: I would say congresspeople from California (e.g. Darell Issa, the current richest congressman) and rich oil states such as Texas.